# Change the time of a subset of a recurring event in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I sent out a meeting invite for a meeting every Tuesday and Thursday from 13:00 - 14:00. Now I wish to modify the Tuesday meetings to be held from 14:00 - 15:00. Is it possible to do it within the earlier meeting invite or do I need to:

- Create another recurring meeting on Tuesday from 14:00 - 15:00
- Remove Tuesday from the earlier invite?

Answer (score 0):

If the Tuesday meeting is to be help earlier for one week only, edit 'Just this one'.

[image]

If you want to edit the series, you'll need to edit it and remove Tuesday, then add a new recurring event for Tuesday.

Answer (score 0):

Please understand that the time of a recurring meeting series is unified, and we couldn't create a separate sub-series under the original series.

For your requirement, if the number of recurring meetings on Tuesday is relatively small and you don't mind to edit and send update for every Tuesday meeting, it's suggested to double-click this meeting and choose "Just this one" to edit.

Otherwise, you may need to create other series on Tuesday and remove Tuesday on original series as you mentioned.

Comment: I think this is _probably_ a feature that MS can take a look at. If I've exactly the same meeting content and purpose but I want the meeting series to be at different slots, it would (again) _probably_ make sense to add a feature making the addition of multiple slots for a meeting possible.

Comment: A meaningful advice, it's recommended to post your idea in uservoice for Outlook, and other users could vote for it, which may implement this feature in the future.